# How to find the entropy solutions and breaking times for the following Riemann problem of the inviscid Burgers' equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

For the inviscid Burgers' equation
$$u_t + uu_x = 0,$$

with initial conditions (correct me if I am wrong, these are piecewise functions)

\begin{equation}
  u_a(x,0)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    -1, & \text{if}\ x<0 \\
     +1, & \text{if}\ x\geq0 \\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  u_b(x,0)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    +1, & \text{if}\ x<0\\
     -1, & \text{if}\ x\geq0 \\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

I am trying to find their unique (entropy) solutions along with their breaking times. I would much prefer if you could explain your train of thoughts on how you obtained the solutions (accompanied by the solutions). Also, am I including the jump condition correctly? I have seen a few posts where the solutions include the speed itself within the conditions, e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750845/burgers-equation-shock-solutions).

This looks very familiar with a lot of the Riemann examples I have seen on the site. Perhaps it may be a duplicate and I apologize for that. I have seen 
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539265/riemann-problem-of-nonconvex-scalar-conservation-laws)  where they discussed the non-convex case but I am not sure if it is applicable.

Here are the characteristic plots for both initial conditions. [image]

---

For $u_a$, we can observe that there is no intersection of the characteristic lines with solutions $u_L(x,t)=-1$ and $u_R(x,t)=1$ but there is an empty V-shaped region with no (classical) solutions.  Furthermore, there is no breaking time since they do not intersect. How do I then proceed to find the weak solutions? Or to be more precise, how do you come up with other solutions? It seems to me from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157585/find-weak-solution-to-riemann-problem-for-conservation-law/3161490#3161490) that since the flux function is convex, you can only create two types of solutions. I don't think a rarefaction is correct since there isn't a point where many characteristic lines are projecting out.

I am aware that a possible solution is

\begin{equation}
  u_a(x,t)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    -1, & \text{if}\ x<0 \\
     +1, & \text{if}\ x\geq0 \\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

which satisfies the Rangine-Hugoniot jump condition, i.e. speed $s=\frac{(1/2-1/2)}{(-1-1)}=0$, and the condition is met where $(1/2-1/2)=s(-1-1)$ (both sides are $0$). Do we still say this has no breaking time? Furthermore, the (Lax) entropy condition requires $u^->s>u^+$ which is not met. Hence, this isn't an unique (entropy) solution.

---

For $u_b$, the lines intersect. The breaking times are computed as $\tau_B=-\frac{1}{u(x,0)_x}$, 
where $u(x,0)_x=\frac{\partial u(x,0)}{\partial x}=\infty$. Does that mean $\tau_B=0$ for $u_b(x,0)?$ (Did I perform the derivative incorrectly? I tried following a similar case from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828508/why-can-a-discontinuous-function-not-be-differentiable).)

In this case, is there even a solution?

---

PS: I realize there are a lot of minor questions contained here, I hope this is okay as I am trying to clear up my confusions on this topic in general.

Comment: For $u_a$, the unique entropy solution would be to fill that empty V-shaped region with a "fan" of characteristics with speeds and values ranging from $-1$ to $1$. For $u_b$ your calculation of the breaking time is correct because immediately after you set this system in motion, the characteristics at $x=\pm \epsilon$ crash into each other. Characteristics can't really "intersect" (otherwise they aren't characteristics) so when they do run into each other, they form something called a shock, which is like a boundary line where characteristics from either side stops.

Comment: I see. So for $u_b$, there is indeed no possible solution since a shock has occurred. Is there any other analysis that can be performed?

Then for $u_a$, so it seems I was wrong and it indeed is a rarefaction? So I would have to use the shock speed to determine the solutions, which means the structure would look like $u(x,t)=-a,$  if $x<st)$.

Comment: For $u_b$ , even though there are infinitely many shocks possible, there is a max entropy shock, so it does have a unique solution. You just have to find the equation for the shock. For $u_a$ it is a rarefaction fan but using the shock speed equation is incorrect since it is not a shock. Instead draw out the characteristics and see if you can come up with a solution for the rarefaction characteristics and their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us follow the method in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3161490). We solve the Riemann problem of the inviscid Burgers conservation law $u_t + f(u)_x =0$, where the flux $f: u\mapsto \frac12 u^2$ is convex.

- $u_a$. Here, characteristics separate. The entropy solution is the transsonic rarefaction wave $$
  u_a(x,t) =
  \left\lbrace
  \begin{aligned}
  &{-1} && x\leq {-t}\\
  &x/t && {-t}\leq x\leq t\\
  &{+1} && {t}\leq x
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
  $$
  The derivation of the waveform can be found e.g. in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2452803/418542).
- $u_b$. Here, characteristics intersect. The entropy solution is the shock wave $$
  u_b(x,t) =
  \left\lbrace
  \begin{aligned}
  &{+1} && x< st\\
  &{-1} && {st}< x
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
  $$
  which speed $s=\frac12 (1-1) = 0$ is deduced from the Rankine-Hugoniot condition. Hence, this is a static shock.

These entropy solutions are valid for all $t>0$. The formula for the breaking time is valid for smooth initial data, where the solution keeps smooth until the classical solution's breakdown.

Note: the slopes of the characteristic lines in OP look incorrect. With the present initial data, these slopes should equal $u(x_0,0) = \pm 1$.

Comment: Regarding $u_a$,would it be more accurate if the intervals are $x<-t$, $-t \leq x <t$ and $x\geq t$? (where the empty region is $-t\leq \frac{x}{t} <t$) and yes, the slopes are inaccurate, I had a constant multiplied onto $u_R$ when I was experimenting. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @mathnoob for the rarefaction, the solution is continuous for $t>0$. Thus, we can use $\leq, \geq$ for the inequalities